# What is the mass absorption coefficient and how it is determined?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, spectroscopy, x-rays

I would like to know what is mass absorption coefficient in the field of x-ray spectroscopy means and how can we determine this value experimentally (or by simulation) and also why for some materials it is hard to obtain (light elements for example).

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_attenuation_coefficient unclear?

Comment: The definition in Wikipedia is good but it didn't answer all my questions that's why i asked here, like how this MAC are measured experimentally and what makes them difficult to measure for light elements.

Comment: Experiment - put different thickness of materials between source and detector. Light elements - they have low x-ray absorption (not many electrons) so you need a lot of material, meaning you need to be more careful about the measurement setup and other losses.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster could you please lead me to some ressources that discuss this in more detail, i will be so thankful if you could!